# How to filter and map array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects,
From which I want to conditionally create another array of objects.

Eg. -

```
var devs = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        age: 26,
        tech: ['JavaScript','React'],
        addr:{
            country:'India',
            city:'Pune'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        age: 25,
        tech: ['Node','AngularJs'],
        addr:{
            country:'USA',
            city:'NY'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        age: 27,
        tech: ['React','AWS'],
        addr:{
            country:'UK',
            city:'London'
        }
    }
]
```

I want an Array of objects who have **'React' in their 'tech' field array**,
 
And only want to display their Name and Tech,
 
**The following is the expected output -**

```
[
    {
        name: 'A',
        tech: ['JavaScript','React']
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        tech: ['Java','React'],
    }
]
```

I know for conditional purpose filter method can be used,
But how do I leave out the unnecessary fields from the array of objects?
Can map method be used here? If so how do I implement it?

**Following is my half cooked code -**

```
var filteredDevs = devs.filter(temp => temp.tech.includes('React'));
```

Comment: regenerate your array

Comment: As you guessed in your title, yes you should use `map`. Have you tried it?

Comment: where do you get `'React'` from `'C'`?

Comment: @Bergi I knew it had to be used, but didn't know how to implement on object array, still learning :D

Comment: @Nina sorry copied wrong console O/P, edited question thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Write a function that can take one of these objects and returns a new object of the desired shape. Then pass that function to `map`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to do it, filter using the **[`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** where you check for the presence of *React* in the `tech` array.

Second step is to map to the desired object by retaining only `name` and `tech` properties from the original object.

```js
const devs = [{"name":"A","age":26,"tech":["JavaScript","React"],"addr":{"country":"India","city":"Pune"}},{"name":"B","age":25,"tech":["Node","AngularJs"],"addr":{"country":"USA","city":"NY"}},{"name":"C","age":27,"tech":["Java","AWS"],"addr":{"country":"UK","city":"London"}}];
const devReact = devs.filter(obj => obj.tech.includes("React")).map(obj => ({"name":obj.name, "tech":obj.tech}));
console.log(devReact);
```

---

You can also do it in one shot using **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**, where you accumulate only those objects having *React* in the array.

```js
const devs = [{"name":"A","age":26,"tech":["JavaScript","React"],"addr":{"country":"India","city":"Pune"}},{"name":"B","age":25,"tech":["Node","AngularJs"],"addr":{"country":"USA","city":"NY"}},{"name":"C","age":27,"tech":["Java","AWS"],"addr":{"country":"UK","city":"London"}}];
const devReact = devs.reduce((acc, ele) =>  ele.tech.includes("React") ? acc.concat({"name": ele.name, "tech":ele.tech}): acc ,[]);
console.log(devReact);
```

Answer (score 4):

I will better use **[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** for this task, to loop only once over the input data.

```js
var devs = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        age: 26,
        tech: ['JavaScript','React'],
        addr: {country:'India', city:'Pune'}
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        age: 25,
        tech: ['Node','AngularJs'],
        addr: {country:'USA', city:'NY'}
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        age: 27,
        tech: ['React','AWS'],
        addr: {country:'UK', city:'London'}
    }
];

let res = devs.reduce((acc, {name, tech}) =>
{
    tech.includes("React") && acc.push({name, tech});
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remove unnecessary fields

```js
var devs = [
    {
        name: 'A',
        age: 26,
        tech: ['JavaScript','React'],
        addr:{
            country:'India',
            city:'Pune'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        age: 25,
        tech: ['Node','AngularJs'],
        addr:{
            country:'USA',
            city:'NY'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        age: 27,
        tech: ['Java','AWS'],
        addr:{
            country:'UK',
            city:'London'
        }
    }
]

let newArr =devs.filter(temp => temp.tech.includes('React')).map(({name,tech}) => ({name,tech}));
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` + `map` functions, however that approach uses two loops for doing what you want.

*This alternative uses the function `reduce` to generate the desired output*

```js
var devs = [    {        name: 'A',        age: 26,        tech: ['JavaScript','React'],        addr:{            country:'India',            city:'Pune'        }    },    {        name: 'B',        age: 25,        tech: ['Node','AngularJs'],        addr:{            country:'USA',            city:'NY'        }    },    {        name: 'C',        age: 27,        tech: ['React','AWS'],        addr:{            country:'UK',            city:'London'        }    }],
    result = devs.reduce((a, {name, tech}) => {
      if (tech.includes('React')) a.push({name, tech});
      return a;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter and map the wanted properties.

```js
var devs = [{ name: 'A', age: 26, tech: ['JavaScript', 'React'], addr: { country: 'India', city: 'Pune' } }, { name: 'B', age: 25, tech: ['Node', 'AngularJs'], addr: { country: 'USA', city: 'NY' } }, { name: 'C', age: 27, tech: ['React', 'AWS'], addr: { country: 'UK', city: 'London' } }],
    result = devs
        .filter(({ tech }) => tech.includes('React'))
        .map(({ name, tech }) => ({ name, tech }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```