# An array of objects that checks each object age and then returns the name of all objects that meet that age

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I had this question on an exam and I got it wrong and I have been trying my best reading through MDN Web Docs but being only a week into learning JavaScript I have no clue what I am looking for.
This what I can recall from my exam, it this fictional state only 15-year-olds and above can be babysitters.  I had used a ".find()" and I only could produce 1 person and it gave me the whole object and they just wanted the name.  Gave a day in a half to find the answer myself but I am lost. HELP!

If you also have a link so I can read up more on this it will be helpful, because other students said they had similar and they asked them to average all the age instead.  Arrays and Objects have me wanting to bang my head against the wall already.

```
function legalBabysitter(sitters){
};

/*Do not modify anything below this line*/

const babysitterArray = [
    {name: 'Peter', age: 13},
    {name: 'Paul', age: 15},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 17}
];

console.log(legalBabysitter(babysitterArray)); // should produce [Paul, Mary]
```

Comment: you should select one answer as accepted answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter and map array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961169/how-to-filter-and-map-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fitler and map like this `return sitters.filter(c=>c.age >= 15).map(c=>c.name);`

```js
function legalBabysitter(sitters){
  return sitters.filter(c=>c.age >= 15).map(c=>c.name);
};

/*Do not modify anything below this line*/

const babysitterArray = [
    {name: 'Peter', age: 13},
    {name: 'Paul', age: 15},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 17}
];

console.log(legalBabysitter(babysitterArray)); // should produce [Paul, Mary]
```

Comment: Thank you, I did know about .map() but not .filter(), I will go ready up on it on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only for exam, you can use for loop, it is very clear.

```
function legalBabysitter(sitters){
  var result = [];
  for(var i =0; i < sitters.length; i ++){
     if(sitters[i].age >= 15){
        result.push(sitters[i].name);
     }
  }
  return result;
};
```

```js
function legalBabysitter(sitters){
  var result = [];
  for(var i =0; i < sitters.length; i ++){
     if(sitters[i].age >= 15){
        result.push(sitters[i].name);
     }
  }
  return result;
};

/*Do not modify anything below this line*/

const babysitterArray = [
    {name: 'Peter', age: 13},
    {name: 'Paul', age: 15},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 17}
];

console.log(legalBabysitter(babysitterArray)); // should produce [Paul, Mary]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const babysitterArray = [
    {name: 'Peter', age: 13},
    {name: 'Paul', age: 15},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 17}
];

function legalBabysitter(sitters){
  return sitters.filter(_ => _.age > 14).map(_ => _.name)
};

console.log(legalBabysitter(babysitterArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know .filer and .reduce, you can do it by .forEach.

```js
const babysitterArray = [
    {name: 'Peter', age: 13},
    {name: 'Paul', age: 15},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 17}
];

function legalBabysitter(sitters){
  let target = [];
  
  sitters.forEach(_ => {
    if (_.age > 14) target.push(_.name)
  })
  
  return target;
  
};

console.log(legalBabysitter(babysitterArray))
```

Comment: You can only use forEach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Here idea is

- Loop through array
- Check if age is greater than or equal to `15` than add name to op
- else keep it as it is
- return op from function

```js
function legalBabysitter(sitters){
  return sitters.reduce((op,inp)=>{
    if(inp.age >= 15){
      op.push(inp.name)
    }
    return op
  },[])
};

/*Do not modify anything below this line*/

const babysitterArray = [
    {name: 'Peter', age: 13},
    {name: 'Paul', age: 15},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 17}
];

console.log(legalBabysitter(babysitterArray)); //
```

Comment: Thank you so much so I guess I have to read about ".reduce()", thank you so much off to MDN Web Docs again.

Comment: @VirgilioRodriguezJr in such cases `reduce` is better option than `map` and `filter` as you don't need to loop twice

Comment: Thank you again.  I am going to read it all, more knowledge just in case I get stuck again.  I will concentrate on the ```reduce```.

Comment: Writing an unreadable reduce instead of a straight forward map+filter to maybe optimize some loop iterations is bad practice.

Comment: @Matsemann can you state some reference about this where it states it's a bad practice ? `Writing an unreadable reduce` really ? it is just having a simple if condition and also answer includes steps how this is working